# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Arduino's [second moderator election](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: VE7JRO]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Anonymous Penguin who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5637724302213120/0).